# javascript if solution if x is greater than any of the array numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

need a little help please for a solution
I have an array numbers and 2 vars.
if x is greater than any of the array numbers,then y becomes the next number...

```
var x = 9
var y = 0
var array = [8,12,16,20,24,28,32]

ex
x = 9
y = 12

ex
x = 17
y = 20

ex
is equal...
x = 24
y = 24
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function .

```
    function findY(x,array){
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
    if(x<=array[i]){
        y=array[i]
        return y
    }
        }}
   findY(x,array)
```

Comment: thanks, this function works for me because i use older scripting language ExtendScript,but  only one thing is missing. if x = 0 ,y should be 0 too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why someone should use this function. Please provide referenced documentation and a working fiddle probably

Comment: Why someone  have to complicate such simple things.Meantime..I solved.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-line function variable that returns what you want or 0 if no no value in the array is greater than x.

```js
const array = [8 ,12 ,16, 20, 24, 28, 32]

const getY = (x) => (array.find(elem => elem >= x) || 0)

console.log(getY(17)) // 20
```

Comment: Great solution, my suggestion is to default to `null` if no number was found, in case you would work with negative numbers. `-3` is smaller than `0` and 0 would be the correct answer, but here you wouldn't know it, because it also defaults to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not a 1 line function but it does in an easy explanatory way.

```
var x = 24
var y = 0
var array = [8,12,16,20,24,28,32]

for (let step = 0; step < array.length; step++) { 
  if(x==array[step]){
    y=x
   }else if(x>array[step] && step+1 <array.length ){  
    y = array[step+1];
   }
    
}
console.log(x,y)
```